# Не получается протабулировать функцию F на интервале Xstart до Xfinish с шагом dX

Tags: функции, pascal

Задание такое: [image: задание]

Мой код ниже(для варианта 21). Компилятор ругается. Не пойму что не так

> main.p(22,44) Error: Incompatible types: got "Double" expected
> "ShortInt" main.p(23,17) Error: Incompatible types: got "Double"
> expected "ShortInt" main.p(24,7) Fatal: Syntax error, ";" expected but
> "identifier WRITE" found

```
var
  xn, xk, dx, x, y, a, b, c: shortint;
begin
  write('xn = ');
  readln(xn);
  write('xk = ');
  readln(xk);
  write('dx = ');
  readln(dx);
  write('a = ');
  readln(a);
  write('b = ');
  readln(b);
  write('c = ');
  readln(c);
  writeln('x');
  x := xn;
  while x < xk do
    begin
      if (x<0) or (b <> 0) then y := a*(x*x*x)+b
      else if(x>0) and (b=0) then y:= (x-a)/(x-c)
      else y:= x/c
      write(x, ' ')
      x := x + dx
    end;
  readln
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

Кристин, паскаль ругается что вы пытаетесь сравнивать и/или приравнивать shortint что целочисленное число -128..127 с числом с плавающей точкой Extended.

Если вы хотите результат с десятичными, то поменяйте тип `y` на двоичное число `var y: Extended;` если вам нужны чистые числа, то меняйте операцию деления с двоичной `y := 4 / 2` на целостную `y := 4 div 2`, потому что оператор деления `/` уже автоматом начинает считать ваши числа как те - что имеют точку в наличии как пример `4.5`

А ещё в вашем примере он очень сильно ругается, что вы забыли поставить `semicolon` а именно знак `;` после окончания каждого выражения.

А ещё он сказал что вы три раза присвоили значение к `y` и после некогда его не использовали.

```
program Project1;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
var
  xn, xk, dx, x, a, b, c: shortint;
  y: Extended;
begin
  write('xn = ');
  readln(xn);
  write('xk = ');
  readln(xk);
  write('dx = ');
  readln(dx);
  write('a = ');
  readln(a);
  write('b = ');
  readln(b);
  write('c = ');
  readln(c);
  writeln('x');
  x := xn;
  while x < xk do
    begin
      if (x<0) or (b <> 0) then y := a*(x*x*x)+b // Тут y :=
      else if(x>0) and (b=0) then y:= (x-a)/(x-c)  // Тут y :=
      else y:= x/c; // И тут y :=
      write(x, ' ');
      x := x + dx;
    end;
    // иииии что делать с Y ??????????
  readln
end.
```

*ps: Я к сожалению очень плохо владею русским языком, чтобы понять ваше задание в целом, но по программированию можете спокойно обращаться.*

Comment: теперь пишет Syntax error, ";" expected but "ELSE" found
Fatal: Compilation aborted

Comment: @Кристина перед else не ставится знак ";"

Comment: Такая вещь как else не может существовать без if или case, так-же как и "(" без ")", и begin без end. То-есть закрывая выражение c помощью ";" компилятор не может понять от куда else взялось и к чему его вообще привязать.